# Facebook API to return list of user that live (publically) in location?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

So in regular FB, not the API, I can type "people who live in Kalamazoo, Mi" and it displays a list of folks who public display that they live in the city Kalamazoo, Mi.

Is this type of search possible with the Facebook API or in anyway that is more usable then the traditional site? If so can anyone help or push me in the right direction, please.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a [Search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/) that allow you to search various types of object.

At present, it only supports a particular type of objects that can be searched. You can find them in the link given above.

I think it doesn't support queries like *people who live in Kalamazoo, Mi* at present. At max, you can search for all the objects at a particular place, using `type=location` and specifying the ID of the place.

For example for Posts at Kalamazoo, Mi, use the following URL with a valid Access Token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=location&place=107740462581860
```

Comment: Thanks! This seem to only return post my friends have made in the location, is there anyway to have it return all public post made in the location regardless if I am there friend or not?

Comment: I think it does not support the same for public posts as of now (at least according to the Facebook documentation). Facebook Search API is not yet developed fully. They'll soon be providing advanced search features using the API I guess.